# transport columns in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a script for creating a table.

```
create table #test_for_TRANSPOSE (id int, vol char(10), su int)

declare @num int 

set @num = 1

while @num <=50

begin

    insert into #test_for_TRANSPOSE (id, vol, su)

         values (@num, (select PATIENTS01.passport_data
           from  PATIENTS01                                                         
          where id_patients = @num),
                @num)                                                
        set @num = @num +1
   end
```

how to transport columns in rows?

I tried to do so, but it does not work:

create table #table_after_TRANSPOSE (new_vol varchar(15))

declare @num_transp int
declare @vol_transp char(15)
declare @count_rows int
declare @column_name char(15)

set @num_transp = 1
set  @count_rows = (select count(id) from #test_for_TRANSPOSE)

while @num_transp <= @count_rows 
    begin
        set @column_name = 'column ' + @num_transp
        alter table #table_after_TRANSPOSE add @column_name char(10) 
        insert into #table_after_TRANSPOSE (@column_name)
             values ((select #test_for_TRANSPOSE.id
                       from #test_for_TRANSPOSE
                      where #test_for_TRANSPOSE.id = @num_transp),
                      (select #test_for_TRANSPOSE.vol
                        from #test_for_TRANSPOSE
                      where #test_for_TRANSPOSE.id = @num_transp
                      ))
        set @num_transp = @num_transp + 1
      end

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: ms management studio 2017

Comment: can you give output formatt

Comment: id         vol              su        
1          MЕ 78594   1         
2          MА 78543   2         
3          РА 34543   3         
4          РН 89043   4

Comment: you want all row in one row?

Comment: What version of sqlserver are you on?

Comment: no, I unfortunately did not manage to write a comment correctly.

All 3 columns need to be flipped and pointed out as strings. For example, in excel, there is a TRANSPOSE function that inverts the table. I need the same in sql

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)